# How to execute at a player holding a specific item in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to direct /execute to the location of a player who is holding a specific item. In this case, an item with the name "Gun". This is the script I'm trying to use:

```
/execute @e {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Firestarter"}}}} ~ ~ ~ 
/summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:0,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I've compiled the script from two working scripts:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ 
/summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:0,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

and

```
/testfor @e {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Gun"}}}}
```

Does anyone know how to put these together? The output of the command block is "that entity cannot be found"

Comment: In the first command, the name of the item is Firestarter. Therein may lie the problem, because you said you wanted an item named Gun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to other commands, like `testfor`, the `execute` command does not support data tag matching. The syntax is:

```
execute <entity> <x> <y> <z> <command …>
```

Luckily, you can turn data tag matching into a scoreboard objective, as detailed in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/231451/74333). Set up a scoreboard objective using

```
scoreboard objectives add hasGun dummy
```

Create a fast clock (setblock/fill clock recommended), and run the following two commands (at the same time, but in this order!):

```
scoreboard players set @a hasGun 0
scoreboard players set @a hasGun 1 {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Firestarter"}}}}
```

You can now use this this objective in a target selector, such as

```
execute @a[score_hasGun_min=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:0,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to `testfor` yourself holding a certain item, all you need is one command block with the following command (for example, we can test for ourself holding an arrow)

```
/testfor @e[type=Player] {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:arrow"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I would use snowballs as a gun, retexture them to look like a weapon, then instantly summon a snowball at that snowball's location- the snowball will give the fireball it's exact momentum before being deleted. First off, put into the chat this command:

> /scoreboard objectives add holding.gun dummy

Then, attach these commands to a repeating/chain command block string (in order)

> /scoreboard players set @a holding.gun 2 {SelectedItem:{id:snowball,tag:{**put any other NBT tags in here**}}}
>
> /scoreboard player remove @a[score_holding.gun_min=1] holding.gun 1
>
> /execute @a[score_holding.gun_min=1] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=Snowball,tag=!snowball,r=2] ~ ~ ~ summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:0,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
>
> /scoreboard players tag @e[type=Snowball] add snowball

Answer (score -1):

The execute command sadly does not support data tags, but can be matched up with a test for command block on a repeater clock with a secondary command of `/summon`, or so put as

```
/testfor @a {SelectedItem:{tag:{display:{Name:"Firestarter"}}}}
```

, then do

```
/summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower:0,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

You can also add particles to make it more detailed, or setblock to fire like this:

```
/setblock ~1 ~ ~ fire
```

with the `/testfor` command, and do this:

```
/execute @e[type=Fireball] ~ ~ ~ /particle <Particle Name> ~ ~ ~ 0.25 0.25 0.25 <Speed> <Count>
```

,although 0.25 can be replaced with how many blocks away from the fireball the particles can reach. You can also do:

```
/execute @e[type=Fireball] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ fire
```

to set the block below the fire charge on fire.

Comment: Putting commands in Pre-Formatted Text, the {} button, makes the commands more readable.

Comment: This solution will check, if any player holding the gun exists, and if, it will summon fireball on commandblock location. Not really working as expected, I would say.

Answer (score -2):

This is what you need to do...

```
/testfor @e {SelectedItem:{tag:{Display{Name: "Firestarter"}}}}
/execute @e {SelectedItem:{tag:{Display{Name: "Firestarter"}}}} ~ ~ ~
/summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {ExplosionPower0,direction:[0.0,0.0,0.0]}
```

That should work :)

Comment: The first command works, but does absolutely nothing on its own. The second command is absolutely wrong. `execute` does not support a data tag, and it's missing a command to execute in the first place.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for telling me that. I will keep this in mind when I am trying to make a One Command thingy :)