# 1.13 Detect if no mobs with a specific tag exist and execute commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My 1.12 solution can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334320/how-to-check-that-a-specific-type-of-entity-is-not-around?rq=1).
When trying to update command blocks to 1.13, I have the following:

```
scoreboard objectives add invert dummy
```

(run at start) then:

```
scoreboard players set FakePlayer invert 1
```

(impulse unconditional repeat) chained into:

```
execute at @e[tag=summoned] run scoreboard players reset FakePlayer invert
```

(chain unconditional repeat) chained into:

```
execute if score FakePlayer invert = 1 invert run say "All summoned animals are dead!"
```

This should reset FakePlayers score continuously until all entities with tag "summoned" are dead, then it should run the final condition. This does not happen, and I can't see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much easier way to do this in 1.13, thanks to the `unless` execute subcommand. The following should work:

```
execute unless entity @e[tag=summoned] run say "All summoned animals are dead!"
```

For performance, including a `limit=1` will let it stop searching as soon as it finds one entity that matches:

```
execute unless entity @e[tag=summoned,limit=1] run say "All summoned animals are dead!"
```

Comment: `unless` doesn't already stop if it finds one entity? What's the reason for that? Just a missing feature?

Comment: Because a repeat command block re-runs the command every tick, regardless of previous results I think.