# How do I execute if there are no non-player mobs in an area?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am attempting to create a wave survival game, in which zombies and other mobs are fought and killed until there are none left, and another wave is started right after their deaths. I cannot figure out how to use the execute command to test whether or not zombies (non-player mobs) are in the area or are still alive to begin wave two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1.13 Detect if no mobs with a specific tag exist and execute commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336266/1-13-detect-if-no-mobs-with-a-specific-tag-exist-and-execute-commands)

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what `/execute unless entity` is for:

```
/execute unless entity @e[type=zombie,distance=..10] run <command>
```